# Establishing an average when counts are portioned

Tags: javascript, math

**The problem**

I have an array which is a property of the class road, which defines the allowed vehicle types on the road, and supplies an approximate portion each type contributes to traffic:

```
[[bus,.2],[smallCar,.6],[bigCar,.2]]
```

I need to calculate the average length of the cars encountered on the road, given the proportion of traffic. (This is needed to do some basic calculations elsewhere in the class.)

**What I have tried:**

I can't quite wrap my head around a better way to do this. In my solution, fidelity changes with an increase in car count. This seems a really slow, heavy handed approach and not right. The function to improve is named averageVehicleLaneSpace.

A very paired down but working version of much larger classes:

```
road = function(){};
road.prototype.averageVehicleLaneSpace = function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var fakeCarCount = 10000;
    for( var i = 0; i< this.allowedVehicleTypes.length; i++){
        var type = this.allowedVehicleTypes[i][0];
        var perc = this.allowedVehicleTypes[i][1];
        for(n = 0; n<=fakeCarCount*perc; n++){
            sum += vehicle[type].laneSpace;
        }
    }
    return sum/fakeCarCount;
}


//define vehicles
var vehicle = {
    bus:{
        laneSpace:14
    },
    smallCar:{
        laneSpace:4
    },
    bigCar:{
        laneSpace:4.5
    }
};

var t = new road();
t.allowedVehicleTypes = [["bus",.1],["smallCar",.3],["bigCar",.6]];
alert(t.averageVehicleLaneSpace());
```

**The Fiddle:**

This Fiddle is the hopeful example above: [The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/921woz83/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average is the sum of the `ratio * laneSpace` for each vehicle type. So calculating the average is as simple as:

```
road.prototype.averageVehicleLaneSpace = function(){
    var avg = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.allowedVehicleTypes.length; i++) {
        var type = this.allowedVehicleTypes[i][0];
        var perc = this.allowedVehicleTypes[i][1];
        avg += perc * vehicle[type].laneSpace;
    }
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and summarize!